# "Unknown Runtime Error" when using Windows Runtime Component with Javascript UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, winjs

I'm trying to use a Windows Runtime Component to provide interoperability between my Javascript UWP app and C# logic that I've written. If I set the minimum version to Fall Creator's Update (build 16299, needed to use .NET Standard 2.0 libraries), I get the following error when trying to call a simple method:

```
Unhandled exception at line 3, column 1 in ms-appx://ed2ecf36-be42-4c35-af69-93ec1f21c283/js/main.js
0x80131040 - JavaScript runtime error: Unknown runtime error
```

If I run this code using Creator's Update (15063) as the minimum, then the code runs fine.

I've created a [Github repo](https://github.com/jimcloudman/winjs-error-for-testing) containing a sample solution that generates the error for me when running locally.

Here's what main.js looks like. The error occurs when trying to run the getExample function:

```
// Your code here!

var test = new RuntimeComponent1.Class1;

test.getExample().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

This is what Class1.cs looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;

namespace RuntimeComponent1
{
    public sealed class Class1
    {
        public IAsyncOperation<string> GetExample()
        {
            return AsyncInfo.Run(token => Task.Run(getExample));
        }

        private async Task<string> getExample()
        {
            return "It's working";
        }
    }
}
```

I can't think of a much simpler test case than that - I have no NuGet packages installed or anything like that. I have no idea what might be causing this. Anyone else have ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing actually async about this function, even as a simplified example

```
private async Task<string> getExample()
{
    return "It's working";
}
```

Also if the said function is already return a `Task` then there is no need to wrap it in `Task.Run` here

```
return AsyncInfo.Run(token => Task.Run(getExample));
```

Refactor the code to follow advised syntax

```
public sealed class Class1 {
    public IAsyncOperation<string> GetExampleAsync() {
        return AsyncInfo.Run(token => getExampleCore());
    }

    private Task<string> getExampleCore() {
        return Task.FromResult("It's working");
    }
}
```

Since there is nothing to be awaited, use `Task.FromResult` to return the `Task<string>` from the private `getExampleCore()` function.

Do note also that because the original functions were returning unstarted tasks, that this causes an `InvalidOperationException` to be thrown by [`AsyncInfo.Run<TResult>(Func<CancellationToken, Task<TResult>>)` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779740(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can also consider taking advantage of the [`AsAsyncOperation<TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779745(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method, given the simple definition of the called function.

```
public IAsyncOperation<string> GetExampleAsync() {
    return getExampleCore().AsAsyncOperation();
}
```

And invoked in JavaScript

```
var test = new RuntimeComponent1.Class1;

var result = test.getExampleAsync().then(
    function(stringResult) {
        console.log(stringResult);
    });
```

Comment: While this is good advice for refactoring the example code that I've provided, as far as I can tell none of it actually addresses the `Unknown runtime error` that I need an answer for. The exception is still thrown with these fixes applied.

Answer (score 0):

This is not proper async method:

```
private async Task<string> getExample()
{
    return "It's working";
}
```

The reason for this is that it was supposed to return `Task<string>`, not just `string`.

So, you should change it to:

```
private async Task<string> getExample()
{
    return Task.FromResult("It's working");
}
```

Comment: While this is good advice for refactoring the example code that I've provided, as far as I can tell it does not actually addresses the `Unknown runtime error` that I need an answer for. The exception is still thrown with this fix applied.